# how to remove twilio logs(message) using "aloha/twilio" package?

Tags: laravel-5, twilio-php

I am using below method to get the logs from twilio account.

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($twilo_sid, $twilio_token);
$call = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array('DateCreated>' => '2016-09-25 08:00:00', 'DateCreated<' => '2016-12-01'));
```

Unable to get the result. Reference link: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/manage-your-call-recordings-with-the-rest-api.html#file-delete-recordings-php-LC1

Above link reference they used to get the call recordings, but need to get message logs.

Comment: You're using `getIterator` function which won't provide you a value but an iterator, did you try with the `foreach` loop ?

Comment: super @AllanStepps .. i got the sms list.. how to remove it.